# WCF Error - Could not find a base address that matches scheme

Tags: wcf, configuration, ssl, web-config

I'm trying to get a WCF web service to work with SSL, as you can imagine it [works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html), however when I run it on the production environments I get this instead:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Despite many hours of wrestling with this problem I still have very little idea what this error message actually means - googling for this error message finds loads of people saying that I should either specify an address in my endpoint configuration or add a base address to my service, however:

- My service worked perfectly fine without specifying either with SSL disabled
- In fact, my service works perfectly fine *with* SSL with the exact same configuration on another machine
- Besides, I've found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249/wcf-service-configuration-file-question-regarding-baseaddresses) which reliably informs me that when hosting under IIS the base address is ignored anyway.

As you can probably tell, I'm currently feeling a very fustrated at my utter failure to achieve what I believed to be a relatively simple task, so:

- What does this error message actually mean?
- How are base addresses determined when hosting under IIS?
- Where can I find reliable, **understandable** documentation about what all of my copy-pasted configuration actually means?
- What do I need to do to get my service to actually work?

The interesting bits of my web.config are:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureTransport" 
                bindingNamespace="http://MyNamespace/Service" name="Basic"
                contract="MyContract" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SecureTransport">
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is off field but can cause this message is if the SSL certificate on the server is expired or not set up correctly.