# How to publish a Web Service from Visual Studio into IIS?

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7, publish

I have written a WCF web service in C#. I had originally self-hosted it and then decided to host it on IIS running locally on my PC. While the service is working, there are several aspects of the deployment process that I don't understand:

Firstly, the URL of this service when hosted in IIS does not correspond to what I specified in my web.config. I had specified "http://localhost:8000/MyServices/OrderService" there and this was used when I self-hosted. Now that I've deployed to IIS, the URL has become "http://localhost/MyServices/OrderService". Why is the URL not picked up from my config file?

Secondly, to host the Web Service, I created a new web site within IIS (in addition to the existing 'Default Web Site'). I set the physical path to c:\inetpub\wwwroot (no idea if this is correct) and left the other parameters as default. I then copied my /bin folder, my .svc file and my web.config to this folder. Is this the equivalent of a 'Virtual Directory'?

Finally, the service didn't work until (within IIS) I selected 'Convert to application'. Why is it necessary to select 'Convert to application'?

Can anyone explain what the correct procedure is to publish a simple web service from Visual Studio into IIS, or point me at some good documentation so I can understand the process?

****EDIT TO ORIGINAL*****
Having spent more time looking into this, I have found the following:

- When I create a web site in IIS, I give it a physical directory of c:\inetpub\wwwroot....etc
- If I then "publish" from within Visual studio, all it's doing is copying all the required filed (like the /bin directory, web.config and .svc file) into the physical directory of the website i.e. - c:\inetpub\wwwroot...

You can perform the copy manually to the same affect.

- Lastly, with regard to the URL of my service not corresponding to the baseAddress section of my web.config file, this has been [answered on stackoverflow previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56249/78522).

The answer is that the baseAddress is completely ignored when hosting on IIS.

Answer (score 14):

If using Visual Studio 2010 you can right-click on the project for the service, and select `properties`. Then select the `Web` tab. Under the `Servers` section you can configure the URL. There is also a button to create the virtual directory.

Comment: I was trying to host a web service through VS 2012 and this helped me.

Comment: Using VS2013 does the job too