# C# web service Deployment to IIS Server

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-6

I have created a web service using C# and I have installed IIS Server 6.0. When I am running web service directly in project its working well. 
Now I want to deploy this service on my system's IIS Server so that my LAN partners can use it. How should I do that? And I want to change default port number of IIS too, how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818983/how-to-publish-a-web-service-from-visual-studio-into-iis check out this link

Comment: what did you end up going with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your web service under `IIS`, setting up a [virtual directory is pretty straightforward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx).

If you're looking to test publish a build, the web deployment project is the best option, you can do it from the command line and in VS.Net, it enables a `"Publish" right-click` option.

Your web service endpoint is your `.asmx` file (no `.cs` file required in your deployment), and the `DLL` in the bin folder contains the code that you wrote for your webservice.

`SOAP, WSDL, Namespace` are all handled by IIS and ASP.NET.

In simple words:

1. create a project of type `"ASP.NET Web service"`.
2. Select `"HTTP"` from location dropdownlist (indicates that the file should be placed on a web server)
3. After Develop your web service, Add web references, select `"browse UDDI Servers on the local network"` option if you want to share the web service among different computer. Enter the source `.asmx` file URL and click `"Go"`.
4. Select `"Add References"` to add your reference name for web service, by default is `"localhost"`, you can give it a name.
5. Declare a reference for your web service in your .aspx file.
6. You can try run your application in other PC.