# Using WCF without specifying the uri

Tags: c#, wcf

How do I use WCF without specifying the uri/url/baseaddress? Is there anyway to make it automatically obtain these things?

I mean I wish to make it work like asp.net sites and webservices work where we don't mention the uri and stuff and it takes care of it by itself just as long as we configure it right in IIS.
I need a similar solution on WCF.

Please help...

Thank you,.

**Edit:
Here's my server side code.I'm using a custom ServiceHostFactory here...**

```
 protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {

        BasicHttpBinding basichttpbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);

        basichttpbinding.CloseTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.OpenTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.ReceiveTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.SendTimeout=TimeSpan.MaxValue;
       // basichttpbinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;

        ServiceEndpoint servicepoint=new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(serviceType));
         servicepoint.Binding=basichttpbinding;

        ServiceHost servicehost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

        ((ServiceDebugBehavior)servicehost.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior)]).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true;

        servicehost.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicehost.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicepoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        servicepoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        basichttpbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 999999999;
       // basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
        //basichttpbinding.MaxConnections = 999999999;
        basichttpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999;
        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        quotas.MaxArrayLength = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxDepth = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 999999999;
        quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 999999999;
        basichttpbinding.ReaderQuotas = quotas;

        //foreach (Uri uri in baseAddresses)
        //{

        servicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basichttpbinding, "http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc");

       // }

        return servicehost;
    }
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. What do you mean by 'how do I use WCF' and 'work list asp.net sites'

Comment: Specifically without specifying an URI. I need to use without specifying the uri/baseaddress and make it automatically obtain them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming you are targeting IIS...)

According to the [Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx) documentation:

> ... Services
>   hosted in IIS do not have the ability
>   to control their base address; the
>   base address of an IIS-hosted service
>   is the address of its .svc file.

Is it possible that your custom service host logic has stopped this behaviour working?

UPDATE:
According to the function docs u can just pass a relative address to the [AddServiceEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585810.aspx) call. Try either empty string or "/".

Comment: Im just specifying the endpointaddress and not the base address.I wish I don't have to specify any address at all. If I compile the code without using any address, it compiles good but throws an error at runtime asking for an endpoint address.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my answer properly. The WCF docs claim the base address is supplied automatically and is "the address of the .svc file"... so in your example that should be http://localhost:52855/WCFService1/Service.svc

Comment: OK I can see you are passing the base addresses in.... in that case you dont need to provide an absolute address for the endpoints, just pass a relative address

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) it allows you to dynamically find endpoints.

Comment: WCF discovery does not let me stay without specifying a uri on the server side. It's for the clients to find the server. I don't mind providing the uri for the clients. My problem is the server..why does the server need to know where it's hosted? I want it to automatically find it...Thanks..

Comment: It doesn't. Show me where in the server side code the url is specified.

Comment: I've posted my code. Tell me how i can change this code so that I don't have to specify any url. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://geekswithblogs.net/dlanorok/archive/2007/07/18/Dynamic-Configuration-for-WCF-Service-Base-Address.aspx This way you can specify the base address in a configuration file. If you do not want that, how would you want to specify and know where your service is listening (what address, what port)?

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249/wcf-service-configuration-file-question-regarding-baseaddresses

Comment: BTW: if you are so worried about hard-coding values, why are you hard-coding all your configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do to your code is this:

```
servicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basichttpbinding, "");
```

to accomplish what you want. As @Schneider pointed out, IIS controls assignment of the service address. The endpoint address will always be relative to the IIS assign address. So the only valid value for an IIS based endpoint would something like:

```
servicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basichttpbinding, "MyService");
```

Which will append MyService to the service URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - this is what fixed it for me:

Add this to the top of your interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "your namespace here")]
```

In your app.config, make sure your service name in the  section is in the form `Namespace.Class`

Hope this helps.