# WCF Client does not consider Host Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have the following configuration file for WCF service. There is a host defined in the config. Still, when I print the service address from the client, it does not know about the host.  The printed result is:

> http://localhost:3187/Service1.svc/MyFolder

**Why doesn’t it take into account the host name? What modification do we need to do for it?**

Note: I am running from VS 2010 for running service and client website.

```
        Service1Client myClientService = new Service1Client();
        Response.Write(myClientService.Endpoint.Address);
```

Client Configuration (Autogenerated by Visual Studio)

```
    <client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3187/Service1.svc/MyFolder"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="MyWCFReference.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="U16990@ustr.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

The server side configuration is:

```
<services>

  <!--MyService-->
  <service name="MyWCFServiceApplication.MyService"
           behaviorConfiguration="WeatherServiceBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80/ServiceModelSamples/FreeServiceWorld"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address="MyFolder"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="MyWCFServiceApplication.IService1" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>


  <behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="WeatherServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: The host address is ignored

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249/wcf-service-configuration-file-question-regarding-baseaddresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a WCF service is hosted in an ASP.NET process, through either IIS or the ASP.NET Development Server (a.k.a *Cassini*), the [baseAddresses setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788995.aspx) in the service's configuration file **is ignored since the service will always be reachable through the URL of the SVC file**.

The URL you're seeing on the client is therefore correct:

> http://localhost:3187/Service1.svc/MyFolder

As you can see, **the base address of the service becomes the URL of the SVC file** on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a WCF client - yet, the config you posted only contains config for a **service** (the server side) ... (the `<services>` section).

I can't see any **client** configuration in what you posted - there ought to be a `<client>` section in your config somewhere

Comment: Updated the post with <client> (Autogenerated by Visual Studio)

Comment: @Lijo: so that service is running hosted in IIS, on the same machine? Then yes - WCF will use `localhost` - I don't think there's anything you can do to change this. Why is this a problem for you??

Comment: I am using Visual Studio for hosting the service. Afterwards I need to move it on to a different server and need to install it in IIS 7. >>> This is not a problem..I want to understand the behavior. This knowledge is needed for me to host in IIS in different server.

Comment: @Lijo The `baseAddresses` configuration setting is ignored when hosting a WCF service in IIS. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Lijo: if you host in the VS web server (Cassini), you will always see `localhost` used - Cassini doesn't support anything else (only works for local connections). If you move your service to a "real" server, then if you define your client, you'll need to use the "real" server's name (or IP address) to define the location of the service